# What are the appropriate ways of performing model selection?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, loss-functions, intuition

I am reading up on model selection and ran into some intresting questions that I would like to understand to build intuition on the topic. My questions were:

1. What are the appropriate ways of performing model selection?
2. Are there any other alternatives for estimation? If so could you list these so I can read up on them?
3. Can we say that the loss achieved on the training data is inappropriate and if so why is this the case?

Comment: You could read Regression Modeling Strategies by Frank Harrell, which covers all your questions (and many others).